# Signing into Chrome with a work email on personal computer on personal network

Tags: privacy, security, google-chrome

I left myself signed in to my work Gmail account on my personal computer. This occurred at home on my own personal network. I also use my work email address as my sign in for Chrome. I had an internet session that was not suitable for work. At all. This included Google searches and YouTube searches.

Will my employer be able to identify what I have been searching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you logged into your Gmail account from your home network they can't see your browsing history. Just don't browse NSFW things in the company's network or while you're connected to the company's VPN.

You can go to `myactivity.google.com` and delete your activity (just in case someone will access your account if you leave it open or other cases).

Comment: Can you only be connected to the company's VPN while on their network, or can you be on company's VPN while at home?

Comment: You could connect from home as well, but it's not your case, since you were using your home PC. You would need to run a software and install a certificate.